# Can't update the shipping amount while checkout in woocommerce(wordpress)

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, plugins

I am trying to add shipping cost to the current order with a custom plugin code. I have write a plugin to display some radio buttons for delivery option and pickup option and embed one javascript file for the radio check event. The following is my plugin code:

```
if ( in_array( 'woocommerce/woocommerce.php', apply_filters( 'active_plugins', get_option( 'active_plugins' ) ) ) ) {

function radio_button_checks(){
wp_register_script('wp_head',plugin_dir_url(__FILE__).'radio_check.js',array( 'jquery' ), '1.0', true);
wp_enqueue_script('wp_head');
}
function delivery_form() {

$content = '<div style="width:90%; margin-top:10px; float:left; background-color:rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.85); border-radius:5px; padding:5%;">';
$content .= '<h3 id="first-self-id"><input type="radio" value="self_product_pick_up" class="distance_between_text" name="delivery" id="self-delivery" />PICK UP AT THE TROPICAL FRUIT TRIBE HQ KICTHEN AT 1/1 GENERAL BRIDGES CREC, DACEYVILLE 2032</h2>';
$content .= '<div id="self-delivery-functionality" class="delivery_functionality" style="width: 100%; display: inline-block;">';
$content .= '<div class="self_delivery_day" style="width: 45%; float: left; padding: 0% 2%; text-align: right; ">';
$content .= '<h4><input type="radio" value="tuesday" class="distance_between_text" />TUE</h4>';
$content .= '</div>';
$content .= '<div class="self_delivery_time" style="width: 45%; float: left; padding: 0% 2%; text-align: left;">';
$content .= '<h4><input type="radio" name="pickup_time" value="9AM-12PM" class="distance_between_text" />9AM-12PM</h4>';
$content .= '<h4><input type="radio" name="pickup_time" value="12PM-3PM" class="distance_between_text" />12PM-3PM</h4>';
$content .= '<h4><input type="radio" name="pickup_time" value="3PM-6PM" class="distance_between_text" />3PM-6PM</h4>';
$content .= '<h4><input type="radio" name="pickup_time" value="6PM-8PM" class="distance_between_text" />6PM-8PM</h4>';
$content .= '</div>';
$content .= '</div>';
$content .= '<h3 id="second-notSelf-id"><input type="radio" value="shop_keeper_delivery" class="distance_between_text" checked="checked" name="delivery" id="other-one-deliver" />DELIVERY OPTION ($12 only)</h2>';
$content .= '<div id="seller-delivery-functionality" style="display:block;">';
$content .= '<div class="delivery-info-text" style="text-align: left;">';
$content .= '<p style="margin:5px; font-size:1em;">PLEASE KEEP IN MIND THAT THIS IS A FROZEN PRODUTS AND NEEDS TO BE STORED IN FREEZER IMMEDIATLY UPON DELIVERY. PLEASE ENSURE YOU ARE AVAILABLE TO TAKE THIS DELIVERY AT THE DROP OFF LOCATION SPECIFIED.</p>';
$content .= '</div>';
$content .= '<div class="delivery_functionality" style="width: 100%; display: inline-block;">';
$content .= '<div class="shop_keeper_delivery_day" style="width: 45%; float: left; padding: 0% 2%; text-align: right;">';
$content .= '<h4><input type="radio" name="delivery_day" value="monday" class="distance_between_text" />Mon</h4>';
$content .= '<h4><input type="radio" name="delivery_day" value="fri" class="distance_between_text" />Fri</h4>';
$content .= '</div>';
$content .= '<div class="shop_keeper_delivery_time" style="width: 45%; float: left; padding: 0% 2%; text-align: left;">';
$content .= '<h4><input type="radio" name="delivery_time" value="9AM-12PM" name="" class="distance_between_text" />9AM-12PM</h4>';
$content .= '<h4><input type="radio" name="delivery_time" value="12PM-3PM" class="distance_between_text" />12PM-3PM</h4>';
$content .= '<h4><input type="radio" name="delivery_time" value="3PM-6PM" class="distance_between_text" />3PM-6PM</h4>';
$content .= '<h4><input type="radio" name="delivery_time" value="6PM-8PM" class="distance_between_text" />6PM-8PM</h4>';
$content .= '</div>';
$content .= '</div>';
$content .= '</div>';
$content .= '<input type="hidden" id="shipping_rate" value="0.00" /> ';
$content .= '</div>';
echo $content;  


} 

add_action("woocommerce_after_cart_table","delivery_form");
add_action("wp_enqueue_scripts","radio_button_checks");
```

and my radio_check.js file contain the following code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

/* Checkout CheckBox Functionality for Self Delivery */
jQuery("#self-delivery-functionality").hide("slow");
jQuery("#seller-delivery-functionality").show("slow");
jQuery("#self-delivery").click( function() {
    if(jQuery(this).is(':checked')) {
        jQuery("#self-delivery-functionality").show("slow");
        jQuery("#seller-delivery-functionality").hide("slow");
        jQuery("#seller-delivery-functionality").find("input[type='checkbox']").prop("checked", false);
        jQuery("#seller-delivery-functionality").find("input[type='radio']").prop("checked", false);
    }
});

/* Checkout CheckBox Functionality for having Delivery Functionality */
jQuery("#other-one-deliver").click( function() {
    if(jQuery(this).is(':checked')) {
        jQuery("#seller-delivery-functionality").show("slow");
        jQuery("#self-delivery-functionality").hide("slow");
        jQuery("#self-delivery-functionality").find("input[type='checkbox']").prop("checked", false);
        jQuery("#self-delivery-functionality").find("input[type='radio']").prop("checked", false);
    }
});

jQuery('input[name=delivery_time]').click(function(){

    if(jQuery(this).is(':checked')) 
    {

        var curr_amount_dol = jQuery('.cart-subtotal .amount').html().replace('$','');


        var total_amount = parseFloat(curr_amount_dol) +  parseFloat(12.00);
        //alert(total_amount.toFixed(2)); 
        jQuery('#shipping_rate').val('$'+total_amount.toFixed(2));
        jQuery('.order-total .amount').html('$'+total_amount.toFixed(2));

    }

});
}); //ready function ends
```

This code is updating total amount (only displaying) along with shipping cost (which is $12) but when i click the checkout button i will not get the total amount with shipping rate on next page.

What should i more add in this code to update the shipping cost on the radio button checked?

Note: right now the total amount is updating through the javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

'woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees' solved my issue. I just added the following code and a little modification on my javascript.

```
function woo_add_cart_fee() {
    $req = $_REQUEST['shipping_method'];
    if($req=='delivery')
    {
        WC()->session->set('ship_val','12.00');
    }   
    else if($req=='pickup')
    {
        WC()->session->set('ship_val','00.00');
    }
    //checkship($_REQUEST['shipping_method']);
    WC()->cart->add_fee('Shipping ', WC()->session->get('ship_val'));
}
add_action('woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees', 'woo_add_cart_fee');
```

and for the javascript i just redirect the same page along with a query parameter 'shipping_method'

```
jQuery('input[name=delivery_time]').click(function(){

        if(jQuery(this).is(':checked')) 
        {
         window.location='http://examplesite.com/cart/?shipping_method=delivery';
         }

});

jQuery('input[name=pickup_time]').click(function(){

        if(jQuery(this).is(':checked')) 
        {
   window.location='http://examplesite.com/cart/?shipping_method=pickup[';
         }

});
```

On radio button checked my page is redirect with the query ?shipping_method=delivery / ?shipping_method=pickup
and my php code in the plugin file check the parameter value and set the shipping rate using:

```
add_action('woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees', 'woo_add_cart_fee');
```

and the fees is update on both cart page and checkout page too.