# How to create a custom pick up and delivery option in woocommerce cart page

Tags: javascript, wordpress, woocommerce, plugins

I have a shopping cart setup on my website using woocommerce and all is set up perfectly What i want to achive there is to create a custom radio buttons to select the option for delivery/pickup. 
If a user will select pickup option then no shipping will be charged or if user will select the delivery option the $12.00 flat rate/order will be charged along with the timings which will save as a meta key and value later on creating order. 
Following is an image to elaborate this perfectly 
[image]

TO achieve this i had already created a custom plugin also where i stuck to add shipping amount. The question is asked here: [Can't update the shipping amount while checkout in woocommerce(wordpress)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31065560/cant-update-the-shipping-amount-while-checkout-in-woocommercewordpress)

but i didn't get any response. Any help will be really appritiated.

Comment: "but I didn't get any response" That other question is only 7 HOURS old! There's no need for 2 questions asking the same thing, when you could have edited your previous question to make it better.

Comment: the previous question is my effort to solve a problem and this question is the problem for which the soulution could be different than mine, thats why i asked it too

Comment: But ultimately you are trying to achieve a specific goal and the questions are related. I don't mean to be a jerk, but have you run a google search? I see several plugins that appear to do what you are asking. (such as [order delivery date](https://wordpress.org/plugins/order-delivery-date-for-woocommerce/) Where do they fall short for you?

Comment: Yes for the date is available but not for different time in the same day. Actually i was stuck in a problem where i need to update shipping cost on checked of radio button. If you see my previous question then you will understand. I  have there shipping value updating but as a fake through javascript but its not updating on checkout

Answer (score 0, accepted):

correct answer is posted here [Can't update the shipping amount while checkout in woocommerce(wordpress)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31065560/cant-update-the-shipping-amount-while-checkout-in-woocommercewordpress/31152567#31152567)

using following hook

```
function woo_add_cart_fee() {
 WC()->cart->add_fee('Shipping ', WC()->session->get('ship_val'));
}
add_action('woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees', 'woo_add_cart_fee');
```

and the date can be inserted by adding a custom field on the cart page using [add_meta_box()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_meta_box)